# Jenkins and Jacoco Integration Test Coverage

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jacoco

I just added Jacoco on my maven dependencies to run integration tests. Then, I created an integration test to test my controller. For example, I tested my HTTP response codes, the headers and the response resources. After that, I created a profile on maven that starts an embedded tomcat. So, everytime I want to run my integration tests, I just put the profile on the maven goals. However, when I execute the build on Jenkins and Sonar reads the reports from Jacoco, the reports says that I have not tested my controller. The question is: How I tell Jacoco that I have passed through my Controllers, Services and Repositories?

Thanks to all!

Comment: whats inside the profile you added? do you pass the agent to the surefire or failsafe plugin? there are some examples in the sonar repository: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any Integration Coverage, or just 0%?
It can be quite tricky to set up Integration Test Coverage using maven and Sonar.

Check there is a jacoco file produced when the IT tests are run.

Check your POM set up compared to this...

```
<properties>
    <!-- Jacoco Properties -->
    <jacoco.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>        
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-unit-test-agent</id>
                    <configuration>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-it-test-agent</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[Link to GitHub example](https://github.com/jenkins957/SonarCoverage)

[BeyondCoding.net](http://beyondcoding.net)

Comment: I'm getting 0%. And yes, my pom file is similar to yours!

Comment: Check you have a jacoco-it.exec file with some content (as defined in sonar.jacoco.itReportPath) in your target folder. This is what Sonar will parse to obtain the stats etc.

Comment: See if stopping the Tomcat instance will flush all coverage data to jacoco-it.exec file. If the file size grows, then try using that final file while doing Sonar Analysis. Also if you are using both Unit and Integration Tests widgets in Sonar (configure dashboard) section, then you'll be able to see both UT+IT combined coverage. What's the value of "jacoco.agent.argLine" variable?